# Can remembered be used with present tense?

Tags: grammar

I just remembered 
I've got to buy the cake

As far as i think i can't say *I just remember to buy the cake*

Because I remember would mean that is in my memory(that won't mean to recall, it would mean to retain or keep in memory)

(the process of remembering is now done and now I know that i have to buy the cake)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "just" with "remember" in the *present perfect* or *simple past* to express your having just remembered:

- I'**ve just remembered** to buy the cake.
- I **just remembered** to buy the cake.

BrE prefers the *present perfect*.

The *simple present* is impossible here.  You **cannot** say:

- *<s>I just remember to buy the cake</s>.

However, without the word "just", it would be possible to exclaim:

- Now I **remember**!  I've got to buy the cake.

Comment: Huh?  You got me confused

Comment: First you said i can use just remember to express having just remembered. Then you said the present simple is impossible here -_-

Comment: I said you can use it in the present perfect or in the simple past.

Comment: I just remember I've got to buy the cake or I just remember to buy the cake wont sound idiomatic. No?

Comment: No, it won't. It should be "I've just remembered" or "I just remembered".  I have edited my answer in the hope of making it clearer.

Comment: But remember also means to retain something in mind. For example my friend wished me at 12:00am on my birthday. I said 'did you remember my birthday'? Does it mean to recall(bring something back into mind) or to retain(keeping in mind)

Comment: Yes, you can say "I remember" meaning that you currently have it in mind ("Do you remember that you need to buy the cake?" - "I remember") - **but** not with "just" - at least not with the same meaning.  (If you said "I just remember I've got to get the cake", it would mean "I only (or simply) remember ...".)

Comment: But in  I just remembered I've got to buy the cake . Here just means recently?

Comment: Yes, usually (it could have either meaning) - and that's what I understood you to be saying.